# Why is my indexed view query performing poorly when queried concurrently?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an indexed view, which i've added a covering index based on how i needed to query that view. Works great.

Here is the query (query fields removed):

```
SELECT      [ABunchOfFields]
FROM        [dbo].[ListingsSearchView][a] WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE       [a].[LocationId] IN (1,2,3,4,5)
AND         [a].[StatusType] = 1
```

See execution plan:

[image]

See client stats:

[image]

Everything looks good to me.

*Usually*, the query comes back sub-second.

However i've noticed on my SQL Profiler trace, a few times this query has taken *2-10 seconds*. When i see them in my profiler, they are usually invoked at the same time.

Here's an example:
[image]

Note the start time.

Why is this query slowing down when invoked at the same time (e.g multiple requests)? The CPU is low, the reads are low, the query plan seems optimized.

Also, this is the *only* query that queries upon this indexed view.

The only thing i can think of, is that during the slowless there are some slow writes to the tables behind this index view, so the index is being rebuilt?

Can anyone shed some light on this please, provide some things to look at, or recommendations? Could i use the `NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMMITTED` hints here?

Thanks.

Comment: This can be caused by lob sided data: Did you check you executed plan (the really used plan)?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen as in, when it's slow? How do i do that?

Comment: I think you can use Parallelism for your query [Forcing a Parallel Query Execution Plan](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx) ;).

Comment: @shA.t i edited the question, i think it was confusing. This isn't a "parallel" issue, it's to do with multiple queries concurrently (e.g from a website)